# g++.exe: @letstr.txt: No such file or directory g++.exe: no input files -first try-

Tags: g++, mingw, codelite

as you know that i'm really a beginner for CodeLite and MinGW, and i don't have any idea how it's works. When i try to build the project, the output said that it's error and i don't know what should i do. I'm using Windows 10.

i simply just follow the steps based on this video for the first try. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGGHxaDxSK4
when i want to apply for some installation, the bar always show up like this 
http://sta.sh/015gez4rfjn0
i even try to mark mingw32-gcc-g++

let me show you my output

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile

"----------Building project:[ letstr - Debug ]----------"

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/asu/Documents/letstry/letstr'

C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/letstr @"letstr.txt" -L.

g++.exe: @letstr.txt: No such file or directory

g++.exe: no input files

mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/letstr] Error 1

letstr.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/letstr' failed

mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/asu/Documents/letstry/letstr'

Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed

mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 2

====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Comment: Someone already answered this for you: you need to rename the file from `_C` to `.c` so it will be passed to the compiler for compilation.

Comment: @Eran which file should i rename ??

Answer (score 0):

> g++.exe: @letstr.txt: No such file or directory

i think your destination file incorrect. if you create C program it must be named with `.c` extension instead of `.txt`.

Comment: the main one or letstr.txt?

Comment: i still don't get it what and where file should be added

Comment: yap. try to compile